# SQL Insert Data to Table from other Table error

Tags: sql-server

I have the following problem: I have 2 tables in my SQL Server 2019. I need to update one table with the date from the other table.

But I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Table 1:

```
ID and Group
1234-2
asdasd -2
dfgfdgdf-2
```

Table 2:

```
id, name, type ...
```

I need to add all the ids from table 2 to the table 1 and add always for the group the value 2

I tried with this query

```
insert into dbo.table1 (Id, Group) 
values ((select [Id] from [customer].[dbo].[table2] where type = 4), '2')
```

Comment: You want `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...FROM`. Not `INSERT INTO ... VALUES`. See [Example H](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#h-using-the-select-and-execute-options-to-insert-data-from-other-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 (Id, Group) 
    SELECT [Id], '2' 
    FROM [customer].[dbo].[table2] 
    WHERE type = 4
```